# What does '--data' mean in the dbt test command?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

A few of our automated pipelines have been using the below **dbt test** command for a long time.

> dbt test --target target_name **--data** --m test_file_name --vars "{'branch':'branch_name','execdate':'2020/01/01'}"  --no-version-check

It worked without trouble until the dbt version was upgraded from 0.17.0 to 1.0.0.

Now, getting an error as,

> dbt: error: unrecognized arguments: --data

I can remove the `--data` from the dbt command now but I am curious to know why the people have added --data in the dbt command during the pipeline development long back and what it is doing in the dbt command?

Any help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is described: [Test selection examples](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/test-selection-examples#more-complex-selection):

> Through the combination of direct and indirect selection, there are many ways to accomplish the same outcome. Let's say we have a data test named assert_total_payment_amount_is_positive that depends on a model named payments. All of the following would manage to select and execute that test specifically:
>
> $ dbt test --select assert_total_payment_amount_is_positive # directly select the test by name
>
> $ dbt test --select payments,**test_type:data # indirect selection, v0.18.0**
>
> $ dbt test --select payments **--data  # indirect selection, earlier versions**

Syntax `--data` was supported in version lower than v.0.18.0.